# Regex negative matching trouble

Tags: bash, regex

I've been frustrated trying to come up with a regex to match strings based on specific file names and am hoping there's a regex ninja (I'll omit the obligatory xkcd link for the sake of time) out there who can help.

I need to match any string ending with ".htm" or ".html" that is NOT (negative matching) preceded immediately by "msg-" followed by 4-16 digits of numbers or hyphens.  The start of the string can be any length or content.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
(?!msg-[0-9-]{4,16})\.html?$
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.  Part of the problem is lookahead matching -- I want to match the whole string if it meets these criteria rather than the first part of the string that doesn't match.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

In case it matters for flavors, this is going into a bash script on Debian.

**EDIT:**

Here are some strings that should match the regex

```
the-quick-brown-fox-jumped-over-the-lazy-dog.html  # ends with .html but no digits/hyphens just prior
wdihwi94uq239ujdf23yefh02msg-2-8.htm   # digit/hyphen count between 'msg-' and '.html' is below 4
ohdf23890yo4c89uwmsg-999-24j345.html   # non-number/hyphen in chars between 'msg-' and '.html'
```

Here are some strings that should NOT match the regex:

```
kh3j42he2-dwfascn233=feufefask0msg-34535-355  # does not end with '.htm'/'.html'
395-u78{efihighqwioh9msg-8455-212.html  # ends with 'msg-' then 4-16 of [0-9-] then '.html'
dfhjwih9asnm)qpzmx.wod923klsj39msg-00-0000.htm
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a string that should not be matched, and a string that should be matched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following Perl regexp matches what you want:

```
(?!.*msg-[-0-9]{4,16}\.html?$).*\.html?$
```

However AFAIK there isn't any place where bash supports Perl regexps. The `=~` operator only supports extended regexps¹, which don't include zero-width lookahead assertions such as `(?=…)` and `(?!…)`.

It is theoretically possible to convert a regexp with lookahaed assertions to one without, but the resulting regexp would be huge. It is much simpler to use two regexps:

```
[[ $string =~ \.html?$ && ! $string =~ msg-[-0-9]{4,16}\.html?$ ]]
```

<sub>¹ First there were *basic* regexps (BRE) (with several syntax variants), then came *extended* regexps (ERE) with more features (and again several syntax variants). Perl added yet more features, and many languages provide perl-compatible regexps (pcre). But bash sticks to ERE.</sub>

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  I think I can fiddle enough to call a perl or python script and run the regex from there, but will give your second example a rip first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try with `^(?!\w+msg-\d+.[html|htm]+).*$`

Also kodos must be your friend ;p (It's a gui application very helpful when messing around with regexpr)

Comment: +1 for the kodos suggestion, I can see that will be a helpful tool.

Unfortunately your regex doesn't seem to work in this case.  I'm also trying to avoid the ^ at the beginning because I'm not concerned with (and don't know) what length or content the beginning of the string will have.

Comment: \S+msg-\d{4,16}.[html|htm]+ if i remember well this regexpr catches the last lines (these that you want to exclude). So you can use it as blacklist filter instead of whitelist filter